# Protractor right click works fine. but context menu not selecting any clue

Tags: javascript

Below is my code.
Need is have to do right click on element and then from contextmenu have to select an option using protractor.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(messagexpath);
     browser.sleep(2000);
     browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();

     //browser.sleep(20000);
     //browser.waitForAngular();
     //browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key)
     //browser.actions().mouseMove(messagexpath).perform();
     browser.sleep(20000);
     var Acceptoption = element(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Accept...")'));
     Acceptoption.click();
     browser.sleep(20000);
```

Got an error Like this, but xpath is correct.

> - Failed: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expres
>     ion //*[contains(text(),"Accept...") because of the following error:
>       SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[cont
>     ins(text(),"Accept...")' is not a valid XPath expression.
>         (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a7
>     2e73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a correct XPath expression :) Don't forgot about square brackets:

`element(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Accept...")]'));`